Did CONMEBOL exist between 1946 and 1961?
According to,
Panamerican Championship

The Panamerican Football Confederation (PFC) was a football
confederation founded in 1946 in an attempt to unite all the countries
of the Americas into a single confederation, It consisted of the North
American Football Confederation (NAFC), the Central American and
Caribbean Football Confederation (CCCF) and the South American
Football Confederation (CONMEBOL), the confederation was dissolved on
1961 with the exit of CONMEBOL, both NAFC and CCCF were merged to form
CONCACAF on 1961

But according to this other link,
1947 SouthAmerican championship

The 1947 South American Championship was the 20th South American
Championship for national teams, and was organized by CONMEBOL

Then, Did CONMEBOL exist between 1946 and 1961 or not?

Why is there any reason to think CONMEBOL stopped existing? Because it was part of a larger confederation?

The poor grammar and lack of sources throughout the Panamerican Championship article give me doubts about its veracity.

@F1krazy Argentina has won the panamerican championship, that's a known fact among argentines. What's unknown is it was made by the panamerican confederation. There were several southamerican championships between 1946 and 1961 ,  It's weird because if South America was under the panamerican confederation, why werent they all panamamerican championships (meaning including countries of the whole American continent) ?
